# proving collinearity of 4 points.

Tags: geometry

Take an acute angled triangle $ABC$. Points $D$, $E$, $F$ are fits of perpendiculars from points $A$, $B$, $C$ respectively to $BC$, $AC$, $AB$. points $P$, $Q$, $R$, $S$ are fits of perpendiculars from point $F$ to $AC$, $BC$, $AD$, $BE$ respectively. prove that points $P$,$Q$, $R$, $S$ are collinear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. $AFDC$ is concyclic.

Hint. [Simson line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line).

Apply the Simson line to triangle $ADC$, using the point $F$ which is on the circumcircle. Hence, this tells us that the points $P, Q, R$ are collinear.

Do the same with $BFEC$. Hence the result follows.